# Edit List contains objects which themselves contain objects, and so on

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a problem with a List of objects ...

This List contains objects which themselves contain objects, and so on ... (all objects are of the same type)

My objects looks like that :

```
  public class MyObject (...)
  {
    ...
    public MyObject[] Object;
    ...
  }
```

I'd like to change some variables of these objects (according to certain parameters), and to do that I think using LINQ.

My problem is that I do not really know how to do something that will pass through ALL my recursive List, regardless of their level.

I hope I was as clear as possible.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive method to do what you want easily enough:

```
public static void Touch(MyObject obj, string otherParameter)
{
    obj.Value = otherParameter;
    foreach (var child in obj.Object)
    {
        Touch(child, otherParameter);
    }
}
```

If you really, really want a more LINQ-esque method, or you do this often enough to need a more generic approach, you could use something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenTree<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    //you could change this to a Queue or any other data structure 
    //to change the type of traversal from depth first to breath first or whatever
    var stack = new Stack<T>(); 
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        T next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (T child in selector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
MyObject root = new MyObject();

var allNodes = FlattenTree(new[] { root }, node => node.Object);
foreach (var node in allNodes)
{
    node.Value = "value";
}
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky He referenced "recursion" in the OP, so I assumed he was familiar with the term.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - didn't notice that in the OP

Answer (score 3):

You could use this recursive extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> fnRecurse)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;

        IEnumerable<T> seqRecurse = fnRecurse(item);
        if (seqRecurse != null)
        {
            foreach (T itemRecurse in Traverse(seqRecurse, fnRecurse))
            {
                yield return itemRecurse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
var allObj = list.Traverse(o => o.Object);
foreach (MyObject o in allObj)
{ 
    // do something
}
```

It's handy because it's generic and works with any type and also because it's using deferred execution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply something like this:

```
static void AddRecursively(MyObject obj, List<MyObject> listToAddTo)
{
  listToAddTo.Add(obj);
  foreach (var o in obj.Object)
    AddRecursively(o, listToAddTo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use this extension method that applies an action to all the items recursively

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                              Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren,
                              Action<T> action)
{
    if (source == null) {
        return;
    }
    foreach (T item in source) {
        action(item);
        IEnumerable<T> children = getChildren(item);
        children.ForEach(getChildren, action);
    }
}
```

You would apply it to your list like this

```
myObjectList.ForEach(x => x.Object, x => x.Value = "new value");
```

The first paramter tells `ForEach` how to access the nested objects. The second parameter tells what to do with each item.